# How to refresh Google Reader cache for a specific domain

Tags: google, cache, rss, blogger, tumblr

Brief history

- `example.com` was associated with a blogspot.
- `example.com` changed to an institutional site and features a small code instructing which file should be retrieved by RSS readers.

  ```
  <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="http://example.tumblr.com/rss" />
  ```
- Google Reader didn't update the RSS to the new blog.
- `example.com/blog` retrieves the posts correctly because it was never used for that purpose in the older blog.

**How is it possible to force Google Reader to update the cached information?** I tried using another RSS reader and it worked perfectly with the new domain. However, when I tried to follow `example.com` in another Google Reader account, it still showed the posts from the older blog.

It's been almost a month that the aforementioned changes were made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding the mentioned code in the old blogspot.